# How to fire jquery keyup event immediately after first letter is typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am trying to build a search tool for a project that i am working on. Basically, i am filtering through a list of items on a page and then displaying the ones that match. The problem i am having is that i am using pagination and whenever the first letter is typed the pagination events don't fire until you type a second letter. The functions at the bottom context.paginate() and context.createPages(4) don't fire when the first letter is typed into the input. Other than that it works great, it's just kind of a nuisance and i can't figure out why those specific events are not firing immediately. Everything, including the unwrap works immediately just not the last two functions. Anyone, have any ideas as to why that is?

```
$(this).on("keyup change", function() {
    var searchVal;
    console.log(searchVal);
    radios = $(section).prev(".filterform").find("input[type='radio']");
    //Find which search filter option is checked and use that class for the find 
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].name && $(radios[i]).prop("checked")) {
            searchVal = radios[i].value;
        }
    }
    var filter = $(this).val();
    if (filter) {
        $(section).find("." + searchVal + ":not(:contains(" + filter +      "))").closest(".projects").slideUp();
        $(section).find("." + searchVal + ":contains(" + filter + ")").closest(".projects").slideDown();
    } else {
        $(section).find(".projects").slideDown();
    }
    $(section).find(".pages > .projects").unwrap();
    context.createPages(4);
    context.paginate();
});
```

Comment: All of your solutions are great but i did some digging around and i found the culprit but i still can't solve it. I need to get the current number of items that are not hidden after the key is pressed. The problem is it wont update the number after the first letter so my events are firing but they are firing the wrong data. here is my item variable: $(this._element).find(".projects:visible") i am trying to update this on keypress but it doesn't do immediately

Comment: I solved it by adding a 500ms timeout for my pagination functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
element.keypress(function(e){
//...
if(this.selectionStart==0){
    //Do something
}
```

}

Comment: can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: See you are using "keyup" it means that until unless you didn't remove your finger tip over the key it wont work. and keyup functionality is different .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an id selector like `"#target"` insteand of `this`:

```
 $( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
//your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
keyPressed or keyUp , keyDown event
```

and read the key directly, without running through the DOM.
You can go with

```
  .shiftKey
```

attribute of the event object, to distinguish upper/lower case

Maintain that string then if you dare to.
However in the next event, your DOM will hold the first letter anyways, then you could go with this "hybrid" approach ...

Comment: this would be a good solution, but my search depends on case sensitivity. Is there anyway to detect and keep the letters case?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may have a similar problem the solution i found that works best for me was to add a 500ms timeout for my pagination functions within my 'keyup' event.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(section).find(".pages > .projects").unwrap();
    context.createPages(4);
    context.paginate();
}, 500);
```